# Best way to start same activity and destroy the previous one

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I am making some webview activity which would be loaded from main activitiy. Is there a way to run, let say every 1h some method which would start webview activity #2 in the background, kill #1 webview activitiy and switch seamlessly as possible from #2 to #1 , maybe some white screen for a second or something, because there are some memory leaks in webview and I would need to destroy activitiy once in a while, but would like to transition everything as smooth as possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that ?

Comment: Whenever you talk about some background work which will wake up after some particular interval, go for [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Because I need to destroy activity once in a while because android webView is leaking memory if activity is not destroyed...

Answer (score 0):

Probably this code'll works for you. I use it to restart my App, when my users change the app's language.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StartUpActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    123456,             //request code ??? some dummy numbers.
                                    intent,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

You can read about the PendignIntent class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

I'm not completly sure, what the `request code` is. I'm using some dummy numbers, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do this, I would suggest wrapping your activity in a "parent" activity and every time you need to kill the "child" (i.e. current) activity, simply transition to parent (with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag) and then have the parent spawn a new instance of your activity. This way you don't have to do anything funky and it's consistent with how android activities work.

Comment: Each time I start another activity, memory usage jumps, how could I clear that?

Comment: That's one of the interesting features of Android that takes time to get used to. Basically, if you start Activity A and then start B from A and C from B (A->B->C), you will most likely have all activities in memory. The reason for this is so that your navigation back works correctly (meaning Android is able to navigate to the previous activity). To fix this, if you go from A->B->A, you can create your  B->A intent with a flag (intent.addFlag(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);) which tells android Activity B can now be killed and freed.

Comment: If you don't, you'll now have A, B and another A in memory (A1, B, A2 where A1 is one instance of A and A2 is another instance). If you do simply navigate "back" by specifying that flag however, your B activity will be cleared (because effectively, A1->B->A1 means B can be killed and A1 reused). Let me know if it's not clear. And please take this with a grain of salt. It's not scientific and I have only put down my own observations after hours and hours of debugging into memory profiling.

Comment: Another way for going from B -> A is to simply call finish() on B which will automatically take you back to A (it will also call onDestroy() on B which allows you to clean up after yourself). The CLEAR_TOP version is more stable and almost required for certain usecases when finish() doesn't work because it also works with situation where A->B->C->D and now you have to go back to A, effectively killing B and C and D.